# See image through object

Tags: animation, mesh, texturing, materials, shaders

I am trying to do something like this
https://twitter.com/i/status/1094431182891159553

Comment: Please make an effort to describe what you want as part of the question. [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add the following nodes:
[image: Galaxy Suzanne Texture Control Nodes]
Here are the things that are labelled above:

> 1) Connect an image texture node to your shader.
>
> 2) Upload the Galaxy Image (You can look for Galaxy Wallpapers for
>   some good ones).
>
> 3) Set the Texture to *Clip* instead of *Repeat*.
>
> 4) Use the Location and Scale to properly wrap the texture around your
>   mesh.
>
> 5) Set the Texture Coordinate Node to Camera

Here's the final result on a Suzanne Monkey with a bit of extra lighting and compositing: https://youtu.be/y_6SRElqMn8

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it works in eevee but not cycles

Comment: The example above was made in Cycles though.... Unless 2.8 has changed how cycles behaves cause the above was done in 2.79.